# how to improve the calculation speed str to float

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
df['distance'].iloc[0]
```

output: '0.02790952'

```
type(df['distance'].iloc[0])
```

output: str

```
df.shape
```

(118884, 40)

I try to parse a string to a float

```
for i in tqdm(range(len(df['distance']))):
    df['distance'].iloc[i] = float(df['distance'].iloc[i])
```

Comment: use `pd.to_numeric(df['distance'])`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick comparison between several methods. I used a single column DataFrame, with 1 million rows.

### Using `.apply(np.float)`

```py
%%timeit 
df[0].apply(np.float)
476 ms ± 6.65 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### Using `.astype(float)`

```py
%%timeit
df[0].astype(float)
336 ms ± 2.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### Using `pd.to_numeric`

```py
%%timeit
pd.to_numeric(df[0])
244 ms ± 2.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### Using `pd.Series` and `dtype` argument

```py
%%timeit
pd.Series(df[0], dtype=np.float64)
333 ms ± 2.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The winner is `pd.to_numeric`! To anyone who reads this, if you think of a faster way, please comment!

Comment: Thank you for the commentary.I try it.